# How do I include a new browser in Fedora's list for "Preferred Applications"?

Tags: linux, firefox, gnome

I'm going to try Firefox 4 in Fedora 13. I would like to do it neatly, meaning it appears as an option in the "System" -> "Preferences" -> "Preferred Applications" settings for all users as "Firefox 4".

Moreover, I'd like it not to ever ask to make itself the default browser when it's first run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Gnome, then this article may help for updating the Preferred Applications:
[Adding an application to the default applications](http://live.gnome.org/ControlCenter/AddingDefaultApplications).

It describes the format of an xml file that defines the new application, to be placed in the directory `$(prefix)/gnome-control-center/default-apps`.

For stopping the "default browser" dialog, you need to set to False in `about:config` the item `browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser`. See this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-459676.html) for all default files. The one you are looking for is either mozilla.js or prefs.js. Writing Firefox configuration files is not my specialty, but [this](http://mit.edu/~firefox/www/maintainers/autoconfig.html) or [this](http://togami.com/~warren/guides/mozlockdown/s) might help.